# why does my code skip the if statement and go to the else when i open the file

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, alexa-skills-kit

my assignment asks me to open a file, but if it doesn't open you are given 3 tries, but when I input the correct file on my second and third try it still give me the error I wrote 'ERROR: File " << input_filename << " could not be opened for input"' and goes to my else statement

char input_filename[90];
    ifstream input;

```
cout << "Type the name of the input file which will hold the simulation results : " << endl;
cin>> input_filename;
input.open(input_filename);
if (input.fail())//if the file doesn't open it will go to the do while loop error message
{   

    int i = 0;
    int h = 0;
     do
    {   
        cout << "ERROR: File " << input_filename << " could not be opened for input" << endl;

        cin >> input_filename;// allows user to reinput filename
        input.open(input_filename);//opens file 
        if ( !input.fail()) 
        {   
            cout << "if statement" << endl;
            h++;// if h doesn't equal 1 it goes out of the loop
        }
            else
            {   
            cout << "else statement" << endl;
                i++;//post-decrement allows for 2 more tries to input file
            }
        if (i >= 2) 
        {
            cout << "ERROR: You exceeded maximum number of tries allowed" << endl;
            cout << "while entering the input file name" << endl;
            return 1;// return 1 represents the error of the input not opening after the 3rd time of inputing
        }
     } while (i < 2 && h != 0);// do while because it need to be a post condition for two varibles


}
```

Comment: Without your code it is absolutely impossible to help you. I see now you posted an image of it. I still can't read what's past the end of do / while loop. It's better to paste it properly here than to show an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you reach line 106, it implies your file input succeeded. At that line you should NOT increment `h`. In fact you should leave `h` at zero if you want to break out of the loop (Assuming the file input worked).